# String scraped from website has '&nbsp;' which outputs as '?'

Tags: c#, string, encoding, formatting

I'm scraping a website that has a string with `&nbsp;` in it.
I store the string as: `string head = h.TextContent;`.

When I output the string I see a `?` wherever the `&nbsp` is in the string. I tried changing the encoding of the string to Unicode and UTF-16, tried replacing the `&nbsp;` in the string itself and also tried to replace the `?`.
Nothing seems to work.

This is a console project in C#.

**What I've tried:**

```
Byte[] encodedBytes = unicode.GetBytes(head);
string decodedHead = unicode.GetString(encodedBytes).Replace('&', ' ');
```

And

```
head = head.Replace('?','');
head = head.Replace('&nbsp;','');
head = head.Replace('&','');
```

Comment: What language setting (lan property in the header) is the webpage?  Html doesn't need encoding if the language is set properly.  The browser will display properly (provided the font is available) on the machine.  Using TextContent instead of OuterHTML may be the issue.  A nbsp is a non breaking spaced and should display as a white space.  Any innertext you should use System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(string).  If the nbsp is in the tag names then it should not be changed and is correct.

Comment: Alright. I'll keep that in mind. The answer below seemed to have worked for me, but System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(head) did not. Thanks anyways though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `&nbsp;` is an HTML entity which stands for [non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space). So when you get the text content, it will not contain the `&nbsp;` in it. Instead, it will contain the non-breaking space character. I guess the console doesn't know how to display that character, so it simply outputs `?`.

If you want to get rid of it, you can replace it with a simple space:

```
head = head.Replace("\u00A0", " ");
```

`00A0` is the Unicode code for the non-breaking space character.

Be careful though if you intend to do more with the text than just display it in the console or some simple manipulation. Usually a non-breaking space is there for a reason as it forbids text wrapping between words. For example, *100 km* shouldn't be wrapped between *100* and *km*.

Comment: Ayy! Thank you so much it worked :D. Space is on the webpage just for formatting, I checked that. Plus, I'm just going to be outputting the text so yeah nothing else needed :)